# scale image inside button with cell size of table - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want a row of buttons in a table, that each is represented by a pic and the button is with transparent border/background.

I put each button in one of the 10 remaining cells of a table using `<td class="col-sm-1">` and I tried to make the imgs `cover` - but the border does not align with the border of the image in the line above:

```css
button.transparent {
  background: transparent;
  border: none !important;
}

.gborder {
  border: 4px solid green;
  /* outline: 2px solid white; */
}

.selectedTD {
  background-color: grey !important;
  border-bottom: 2pt solid grey;
}

span.smallText {
  color: white;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.imgButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
/* background-size: contain; */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover caption-top">
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <h5 class="text-start">click for details:</h5>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 ">   
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">   
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>   
            </td>            
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button> 
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>  
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button> 
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                </button>   
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-2 selectedTD">
                <h5 class="text-white text-start">detailed information:</h5>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">   
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                  <div class="row">
                      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                           class="gborder">
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                  </div>
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">   
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                  <div class="row">
                      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                           class="gborder">
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                  </div>
                </button>    
            </td>            
            <td class="col-sm-2 selectedTD" colspan="2">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                  </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD selectedTD">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>   
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
                <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>   
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Surrounding variables:

- first line ("click for details") has always 1 `col-sm-2` and 10 `col-sm-1` entries
- second line always has 2 `col-sm-2` and 7 `col-sm-1` entries
- pictures must keep their aspect ratio

How can I align the border of the second line with the first one in case of browser window size changes? I'd like the one img in line two with `col-sm-2` class to be exactly 2 items big, and the borders to align everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add Bootstrap's `row` class to your `tr` element, to make the columns aligned across rows.

```js
<tr class="row">
```

To remove the space around the image, remove the padding like this:

```css
.row img {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Also, you should add parent `row` to your `img` elements in the first row, to fix the misaligned image borders.

Your modified snippet:

```css
button.transparent {
  background: transparent;
  border: none !important;
}

.gborder {
  border: 4px solid green;
  /* outline: 2px solid white; */
}

.selectedTD {
  background-color: grey !important;
  border-bottom: 2pt solid grey;
}

span.smallText {
  color: white;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.imgButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
  /* background-size: contain; */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 48px;
}

.row img {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover caption-top">
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-sm-2">
        <h5 class="text-start">click for details:</h5>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 ">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                         </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                       <div class="row">
 <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                        </div>
 </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                       <div class="row">
 <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                      </div>
   </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                        <div class="row">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                        </div>
 </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                      <div class="row">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                         </div>
</button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                        <div class="row">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                        </div>
 </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                       <div class="row">
 <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                        </div>
 </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                        <div class="row">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                         </div>
</button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                        <div class="row">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                        </div>
 </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                                        <div class="row">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                         class="gborder imgButton">
                                         </div>
</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-sm-2 selectedTD">
        <h5 class="text-white text-start">detailed information:</h5>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                  <div class="row">
                      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                           class="gborder">
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                  </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                  <div class="row">
                      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                           class="gborder">
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                        <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                  </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-2 selectedTD" colspan="2">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                  </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 selectedTD">
        <button class="transparent" disabled>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/74/c0/8074c06da560a31b0aff51fad8b93cc1.jpg" 
                             class="gborder">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                          <span class="text-start smallText">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but your images are also not with "fitting border". There is space between the border and the image (look at the second row specially).

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Works for you now as expected?

Comment: Now the border is perfect, but the images are no longer aligned across the rows.

Comment: Fixed, in your first row the surrounding `.row` elements were missing for the `img` elements.

Comment: would it be possible to make some space between the borders?

Comment: Yes, just add some padding like this: `.row { padding: 0.4em; }`

Comment: Would you mind taking a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886870/how-to-vertically-align-a-text-in-a-bootstrap-5-table-cell?noredirect=1#comment125319738_70886870 with `class="row"` in the `tr` the alignment of all my `td` in this row does not work any more :(

Comment: Will take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241487/discussion-between-xtlc-and-gru).