# how to vertically align a text in a bootstrap 5 table cell?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I created a table and I want one of the cells to have a vertical alignment. The bootstrap 5 documentation [states](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/):

> Change the alignment of elements with the vertical-alignment
> utilities. Please note that vertical-align only affects inline,
> inline-block, inline-table, **and table cell elements**

I just made a small comparison table, to demonstrate my disarray:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-dark">
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="col-sm-2 align-middle">not aligned</td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg/320px-Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg.png" width="64px" height="48px">
                    </div>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-9" colspan="9"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-dark">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-2 align-middle">aligned</td>
            <td class="col-sm-1">
                <button>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg/320px-Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg.png" width="64px" height="48px">
                    </div>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-9" colspan="9"></td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So why does the first table not have a vertically correctly aligned text like the second one?

I also tried to add a flex box: `<div class="d-flex align-items-center">...</div>`. Same result. I need that `class="row"` in my `tr` because of horizontal alignment of table elements. How can I still get vertical aligned items in my first cell?

Comment: My guess is because you have the `row` class set on the `<tr>`. This sets the `<tr>` to `display: flex`, which causes its children, the table cells, to behave as though they were `display: block`. The class `align-middle` sets `vertical-align: middle` which only works on elements that are `display: inline` or `display: table-cell`. (Bootstrap's `row` class has nothing to do with tables.)

Comment: You say that you need that `row` class for horizontal alignment, but it seems to mess that up as well.

Comment: Have you tried adding `align-items-center` to  your `tr` element?

Comment: @dalelandry this actually alignes the cells' text correctly, but the background is now only in the area of the text. I think I need a `<td>` wide solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean both horizontal and vertical centering, right?

As already pointed out in the comments, mixing tables with Bootstrap's `row` class causes issues with aligning items.

But, **if** you want to keep the current layout as it is, you could use `display: contents` on the element with class `row`. This makes the children position relative to the parent of the element. Read more in the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box).

Your modified snippet:

```css
tr.row {
  display: contents
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-dark">
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-sm-2 align-middle">now aligned</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg/320px-Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg.png" width="64px" height="48px">
                    </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-9" colspan="9"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-dark">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-sm-2 align-middle">aligned</td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <button>
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg/320px-Flag_of_Papua_New_Guinea.svg.png" width="64px" height="48px">
                    </div>
                </button>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-9" colspan="9"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't let you wait for the correct answer but till that time you must look upon the following [1]: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/  which states the Vertical Alignment of item and item container in Bootstrap 5.
You can use the same property to set the alignment for the table cell and item in that table cell.

Cheers and Enjoy Development

Comment: Also you can use W3Schools Bootstrap Section for some updated content and content property to use.

Comment: you provided the same link I had in my question, I am not clear on which way to proceed in order to achieve my desired output.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't considered valuable on SO. Please see [answer].